# Deno virtual DOM or server side rendering for web components

Tags: server-side-rendering, deno

For instance, let's assume that I have a simple web component stored on server as `component.js`:

```
export default class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
    const element=document.createElement('div')
    element.setAttribute('class','qwe')
    this.shadowRoot.append(element)
  }
}
```

On client side I can use this component to produce some HTML:

```
import Component from 'component.js'
customElements.define('my-component',Component)
const element=document.createElement('my-component')
document.body.append(element)
```

Can I do the same on server side and get stringified HTML without changing my components code? One particular use case for that is if server got request header `sec-fetch-mode: navigate` I want to return already rendered HTML page otherwise I want to return component itself.

Answer (score 2):

Deno does not include the DOM APIs needed for the creation or serialization of elements (e.g. [`window.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document)). However, third-party modules exist to provide such functionality and are included as suggestions in the manual.

Quoting from section [8.7.1](https://deno.land/manual@v1.31.3/advanced/jsx_dom/overview#document-object-model-dom) in the manual:

> While Deno has a lot of web platform APIs, it does not support most of the DOM APIs related to visual representation.

For more information, see section 8.7 [Using JSX and the DOM](https://deno.land/manual@v1.31.3/advanced/jsx_dom).